I am doing Prisma create user query for MongoDB and i am unsure if i am using the correct syntax
I tried not providing the createdAt and updatedAt and v fields when creating the user in mongoDB but it seems like these 3 are mandatory.
I kept getting this error
Invalid prisma.users.create() invocation in
C:\Users\Akshit\Desktop\pvtideanest\server\controllers\auth.controllers.js:32:44
when i didnt provide these 3 fields once i changed my route as
A new user is getting created as expected but is it how it is supposed to be done? Any response is greatly appreciated.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Format your code and make use of block quotes ```like this```.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
